# a version of the comparison lemma (harmonic functions)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve this exercise :

Consider $U$ open , bounded set in $R^n$ with smooth  boundary. Let $u \in C^2(U)$ a harmonic function. Suppose that for each $x \in \partial U $ there exists a sequence $a_k$ in $U$ with

$$ a_k \rightarrow x$$
and

$$ \limsup \ u(a_k) \leq M$$

where $M$ is a constant independent of $x$. Show that $u \leq M $ in $U$.

To prove this exercise I am trying to use the maximum principle :

Consider $U$ an open, bounded set in $R^n$ with smooth  boundary.  Let $u \in C^2(U) \cap C(\overline{U})$ a harmonic function. Then the maximum and minimum occurs in the boundary of $U$.
Someone can give me a hand to prove the exercise?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $a_k\to x$?

Comment: yes. I fixed the error. thanks!

Comment: In the case where $U$ is an interval $(0,1)$ you can get this result by applying the maximum principle to $(x_n,y_n)$ where $x_n \to 0,y_n \to 1$ are the sequences guaranteed by the hypothesis.  I'm unsure how to generalise this at the moment but it's a starting point.

Comment: Where do you found this problem?

Comment: @Tomás I found in a exam of my friend. Now me and my friends solved the exercise. Thanks for your attention =)

Comment: Could you please post a solution? Thank you.